# Not able to open a solution file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

**Scenario:** I started doing development on C# and MongoDB. I just got a good [demo project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273145/Using-MongoDB-with-the-Official-Csharp-Driver) which I have downloaded.

The following is the content of the `.sln` file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "IntroMongo", "IntroMongo\IntroMongo.csproj", "{9D4B1119-A3EA-4B82-8979-4C1B6BDB56B0}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {9D4B1119-A3EA-4B82-8979-4C1B6BDB56B0}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {9D4B1119-A3EA-4B82-8979-4C1B6BDB56B0}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {9D4B1119-A3EA-4B82-8979-4C1B6BDB56B0}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {9D4B1119-A3EA-4B82-8979-4C1B6BDB56B0}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

**Issue:** Not able to open the solution in Visual Studio 2010

It is throwing the following error message:

```
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.
Please see the Output Window for details.
```

**Know Information:**
Some further research and I found following:
[List of known project type Guids](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx).
My `.sln` file contains:

```
Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "AddNumbers", "AddNumbers.csproj", "{2C81C5BB-E3B0-457E-BC02-73C76634CCD6}"
```

The link shows:

```
Project Type     Description    Project Type Guid<br>
Windows (C#)    {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
```

So it's Windows C#

Output window shows the following:

```
D:\IntroMongo\IntroMongo\IntroMongo.csproj : error  : The project file 'D:\IntroMongo\IntroMongo\IntroMongo.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

**Question:** How can I open and run the project on Windows 7 64-bit machine in Visual Studio 2010?

Advance Thanks.

---

**Update based on the comments:** 
The *.csproj contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{9D4B1119-A3EA-4B82-8979-4C1B6BDB56B0}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>IntroMongo</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>IntroMongo</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0\lib\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Bson, Version=1.2.0.4274, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>bin\MongoDB.Bson.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.2.0.4274, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>bin\MongoDB.Driver.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Controllers\RemarkController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\UserController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\MongoWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Remark.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\User.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_222222_256x240.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_454545_256x240.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_888888_256x240.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.accordion.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.all.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.base.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.button.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.core.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.datepicker.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.dialog.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.progressbar.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.resizable.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.selectable.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.slider.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.tabs.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.theme.css" />
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="Content\Site.css" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.5.1.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\modernizr-1.7.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\modernizr-1.7.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\MicrosoftAjax.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js" />
    <Content Include="Views\Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\Remark\Index.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\User\Index.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\User\New.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\User\Edit.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target> -->
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>3228</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>
          </IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

---

**Visual Studio Version Details**:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01018-532-2002102-70881
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70881
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70881
Microsoft Visual F# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01018-532-2002102-70881
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01018-532-2002102-70881
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2529927)   KB2529927
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529927.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2548139)   KB2548139
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548139.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2549864)   KB2549864
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2565057)   KB2565057
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565057.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2635973)   KB2635973
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635973.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2736182)   KB2736182
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182.

Indent Guides   12.1
Indent Guides

Adds visual guides at each indentation level.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

MySQL Connector/Net   6.5.4
Data design and management tools for MySQL.  Copyright © 2007-2011 Oracle, Inc.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2645410)   KB2645410
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2645410.
```

Comment: `One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly.
Please see the Output Window for details.`
might be worth it to show the information from the output window

Comment: Did you have a look at the Output window as instructed. What does it say?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Mongo DB. Do you have C# Projects installed in your Visual Studio?

Comment: @tucaz yes, C# Projects installed in my Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @DanielHilgarthL It says "The project type is not supported by this installation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your update, it looks like the project is an `MVC` project. Do you have this installed?

If not, please install it from here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Comment: C# Projects installed in my Visual Studio 2010.. (double verified)

Comment: Can you post the **project** file contents please?

Comment: Thank you. I created the project in mvc 3 and forgot to install it before opening.

Answer (score 0):

The original project was created using VS2012 judging by the format version, you need VS2010 SP1 to open a 2012 project in 2010. Have you got VS2010 SP1 installed?